# DeploymentItem-Attribut for all files and folders in folder

Tags: c#, unit-testing, deploymentitem

I want to deploy all files in folders which are in a directory within a unit-test. To deploy eacht item through the DeploymentItem-Attribut is too much.

I tried something like

```
[DeploymentItem(".\\")]
```

or

```
[DeploymentItem("*.*")]
```

but both don't work.

Does anybody knows how i can deploy all files with all subfolders by the Deployment-Attribut?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DeploymentItemAttribute does not take a pattern to search and deploy.
Read more about it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms245570%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

You need to use each of the file names for the same or create a custom attribute which takes a pattern and deploys the item to our output directory.

Comment: The link that you provided appears to suggest that you can do: [DeploymentItem(@"Testfiles\")]
Copies all the files and folders in the Testfiles folder from the build output folder to the deployment folder. Subfolders are replicated in the deployment folder.